# Using python code how do i get the disks name and disk state in azure

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am unable to get the disks name and disk state details using python:

```
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials( client_id = CLIENT, secret = KEY, tenant = TENANT_ID )
subscription_id = ''
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
rg = 'shuilinux'
disks = compute_client.disks.list_by_resource_group(rg)
for disk in disks:
    print disk
```

Comment: What code have you written to do this and what issues are you facing with this code?

Comment: credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)

subscription_id = ''

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

rg = 'shuilinux'

disks = compute_client.disks.list_by_resource_group(rg)
for disk in disks:
    print disk

Comment: by using this iam getting only disk in that resource group i need all disks information

Answer (score 0):

Answering to you question, below code gives you the disks names and disk state

> ```
> credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials( client_id = CLIENT, secret = KEY, tenant = TENANT_ID )
> subscription_id = ''
> compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
> rg = 'shuilinux'
> disks = compute_client.disks.list_by_resource_group(rg)
> for disk in disks:
>     print disk.name
>     print disk.disk_state
> ```